# How to change a text input in output with shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to encrypte then decrypte a message that a user would write on shiney:

```
ui = basicPage(textInput("txt", "Enter the text to display below:"),  textOutput("text"),  verbatimTextOutput("verb"))


server <- function(input, output) {  


dataInput <- reactive({input$txt

})
  
  K <- ""
  
  for(i in (1:nchar(dataInput()))){
    l <- substring(reactive(dataInput), i,i)
    l <- swapletter(l)
    K <- paste(K, l, sep ="")
  }
  
  
  K

  library("Brobdingnag")
  
  
  
  CODE <- reactive(fromstringtovec(K))
  Alpha <-reactive(Alphabetfreq(K))
  
  for(it in 1:10){
    #on sort les bigrammes
    bigrammecode <- str_replace(CODE," ","")
    #calcul de la qualité
    QK <- qualité(bigrammecode)
    #premierswap qui réactualise le code et l'alphabet
    Kswap <- rewriteVEC(Alpha, CODE)
    CODENEW <- Kswap[28:length(Kswap)]
    Alphanew <- Kswap[1:26]
    
    #on sort les bigrammes
    bigrammecodenew <- returnbigram2(CODENEW)
    
    QKswap <- qualité(bigrammecodenew)
    
    if(QKswap > QK){ 
      CODE <- CODENEW
      Alpha <- Alphanew}
    else{
      U <- runif(1)
      if (U < (QKswap/QK)){
        CODE <- CODENEW
        Alpha <- Alphanew}
      else{}
    }
    
    if(it == 10){
      print(it)
      output$text <- renderText(print(CODE()))
      output$verb <- renderText({ input$txt })}
  }
}
```

I have the Error :Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.

- You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
  57: 
  Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
- You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Please share which of the solutions listed here you already tried and did not work: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+Operation+not+allowed+without+an+active+reactive+context.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in the code. I strongly suggest that you read up on the basics.

- Code on the top level of the server function will only be run once. I assume that is not what you intended.
- Do not use `reactive` like any other statement. Your error message comes from `substring(reactive(dataInput), i,i)`. You cannot use it like that. The result of `reactive(dataInput)` is a function that you cannot use. Use `reactive(dataInput)` only on the top level of the server function.
- Avoid nesting reactive contexts. `dataInput <- reactive({input$txt})` is possible but unnecessary.

The following code is a template to show you how you can make it work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  textInput("txt", "Enter the text to display below:"),
  textOutput("text"),  
  verbatimTextOutput("verb")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # For demonstration purposes; use your own function
    swapletter <- function(Char) {
      if (nchar(Char) < 1) return("")
      
      Upper <- TRUE
      index <- which(LETTERS == Char)
      if (length(index) == 0) {
        index <- which(letters == Char)
        Upper <- FALSE
      }
      if (length(index) == 0) return(Char)
      
      obfuscated <- index + 12 
      obfuscated <- ifelse(obfuscated <= length(letters), obfuscated, obfuscated - 26)
      if (obfuscated < 1 || obfuscated > length(letters)) return("")
      return(ifelse(Upper, LETTERS[obfuscated],letters[obfuscated]))
    }
    
    # Indicates that the encryption succeeded
    EncryptOk <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
    #
    output$text <- renderText({
      K <- ""
      EncryptOk(TRUE)
      
      # All the transformations you want to do, you need to do here!!!
      
      for(i in (1:nchar(input$txt))) { # sample code
        l <- substring(input$txt, i, i)
        L <- swapletter(l)
        if (l == L) EncryptOk(FALSE)
        K <- paste(K, L, sep ="")
      }
      
      if (EncryptOk())
        return(K)
      else
        return("")
    })
    
    # 
    output$verb <- renderText({
      if (EncryptOk()) 
        return(isolate(input$txt))
      else
        return("")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```